# Opencart to enable autocomplete for name AND model

Tags: php, opencart

I am using OC 2.2.0. On frontend, I need autocomplete both on name and model. Right now, only name autocompletes. In catalog/model/catalog/product.php I changed

```
$sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
```

to

```
$sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) LIKE '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%'";
```

But still can't get autocomplete on model. Instead, I always must enter the whole model name, but it must be autocomplete. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of researching and looking at the code, I managed to understand and fix my problem. I was looking at all the wrong places. The ONLY file which needs changing is `getdata.php` which is in the root of your OC. So, default autocomplete is for the product name only. It is defined in this file like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT pd.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p," . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd WHERE p.status = 1 AND p.product_id = pd.product_id AND language_id = '".$id."' AND UPPER(pd.name) like UPPER('%$q%') GROUP BY pd.product_id ORDER BY pd.name ASC";
   $res = mysql_query($sql);
   if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
       while($ro = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

           $name = str_replace( array( '\'', '"', ',' , ';', '<', '>','&quot','&'), ' ', $ro['name']);
       //$str[]= $name."\n";
       echo $name."\n";
       }
   }
```

Now, all you need to do is add the exact query for model or whichever database field in the oc_product table you need autocomplete for. Meaning, for example, copy the name query and replace `pd.name` with `p.model` and wherever you find `['name']`replace with `['model']`. And voila! I really hope this helps someone, as up until today I had trouble realizing this myself.